# Open a website from UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Currently I have a UITabBarController with 4 items on it that all have associated view controllers. I'd like to add a 5th tab bar item that does not go to a new view controller, but rather launches a website in Safari. Essentially, it acts like a UIButton.

So the behavior would be:

User is on tab 1. 
User clicks on tab 5 (tab 5 turns blue for an instant).
View does not change.
Website opens in Safari (I know how to do this part)
When user returns to the app, they are still on tab 1 (tab 1 is blue)

Any ideas?

Currently my UITabBarController is setup like this (where localControllerArray is an array of 4 UINavigationControllers):

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
[localControllersArray release];    
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[tabBarController release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know how the `UITTabBarController` has a delegate property? Create an object that implements the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol, and set it as a delegate. Then, when you select any of the tabs, delegate's [tabBarController:didSelectViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate) will get called. In it you can check to see if your 5th tab was tapped. In that case, simply set the `selectedIndex` property of the tabbarcontroller to what you want. That's it.

PS, Actually you should just call [tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)
 instead this way the view won't switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
switch(mytabbar.selectedIndex)
{
case 0:
    [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab1_sel.png"]];
    [imageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab2.png"]];
    [imageView3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab3.png"]];
    [imageView4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab4.png"]];
    [imageView5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab5.png"]];
    break;

case 1:
```

its working for me try it ... put it in appdelegate method.